# Vue JS - Can't access props on the mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In allImport.vue page I am passing props like that:

```html
<sidebarProductDetails :row="singleRow" />
```

sidebarProductDetails.vue page I have this code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ row }}</pre>
    <!-- I can see all the data in this row object -->
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "vue-awesome-swiper"
import { BImg } from "bootstrap-vue"
import "swiper/css/swiper.css"

export default {
  props: ['row'],
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
    BImg,
  },    
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.row);
    // Can't get anyting showing me undefined
  },
}
</script>
```

Here you can see the I just log the `row` props on the **mounted** hook but nothing is showing. The interesting things is that I can see all the data inside the  wrapper.

Is there anything I am dong wrong?

Comment: what about `nextTick()` ? you can use the nextTick inside the mounted hook.

Comment: do you mean this `this.$nextTick(() => {
          console.log(this.row)
      });`

Comment: maybe `singleRow` is undefined?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw i think no becuase I cna get data inside the `<template></template>`

Comment: yes, then you should be seeing the row value.

Comment: @yvl No, I can't see.

Comment: A prop is sync and should be available straight away, do you have anything in your Vue devtools (inspect the component)? There should not be anything buggy here.